# Android WebView font and pictures size

Tags: android, web, webview, size

I'm trying to make this fake app using a fullscreen `webview`. I made the web pages using the browser but using the `webview` everything is huge. 
i tried the viewport meta, the `setUseWideViewPort` command, but it doesn't help.
I almost fixed that using:

```
webSettings.setTextZoom(30);
```

But the pictures and element sizes are still big ! How can I fix that ? Thanks.

PS : I cant change the viewport width meta to a specific pixel size because it mess the `css` "width:100%".

Answer (score 0):

You gotta set the textsize using the html/css code.

Comment: I know that feeling :) But it's the only way to size stuff you're opening in the webview :/ I've worked with a lot of user generated content in apps for large customers and there's just no shortcut. If you wouldn't mind, accept the answer so I can satisfy my meager ego with fictitious internet points :)